# Display last logon date on profile

Tags: 7, users

I have D7 with profile2 how can I display the user last active date (last login date) on the users profile so other users know that they are an active user. It doesn't have to the actual date it can say something like "Active within the last week"

Comment: check here https://drupal.org/node/54144

Answer (score 1):

You can implement [template_preprocess_user_profile](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.pages.inc/function/template_preprocess_user_profile/7)

In your theme's template.php file add:

```
function MYTHEMENAME_preprocess_user_profile(&$vars) {
  $vars['user_profile']['last_login'] = array(
      '#markup' => t('Last login') . ': ' . format_date($vars['user']->login, 'medium'), // prints the actual last login time using the medium date format
      '#weight' => 99, // defines location
  );
}
```

Clear the cache and check the user profile page (e.g. /user/1)

Answer (score 1):

If no coding needed,
use module linked below

> https://www.drupal.org/project/login_history

Answer (score 0):

it depends on where do you want to implement this but it just to lines:

```
// Load user object.
global $user;

// Get the timestamp of last login
$user->login;
```

then you'll have the option on how to output this(e.g):

```
date('d M Y h:i', $user->login);
```

or use it a Drupal way by implementing [format_date()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/format_date/7.x) which can be use like this:

```
format_date($user->login, 'custom');
```

you can make your own custom format to have as you mentioned!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple and lightweight module here

https://www.drupal.org/project/last_login